# How to fade in/out a navbar, which gets fixed after scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So far I have a navbar with transparent background when you land on the page. After a certain threshold of scrolling, it gets the class navbar-fixed, which makes the navbar fixed and changes the appearance.

However, I would like it to have a smooth fade in and fade out effect when it appears (and when you scroll up again, disappears).

How could I achieve that? Jquery fadeIn and fadeOut does not work since it actually totally hides the navbar with the fadeOut.

```
<div id="nav" class="navbar-trans">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function () {
      //if you hard code, then use console
      //.log to determine when you want the 
      //nav bar to stick.  
      console.log($(window).scrollTop())
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 280) {
      $('#nav').removeClass('navbar-trans').addClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 281) {
      $('#nav').removeClass('navbar-fixed').addClass('navbar-trans');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a css transition

```
#nav {
    transition: opacity 0.25s;
}

.navbar-fixed {
    opacity: 0.75
}

.navbar-trans {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @realseanp says, CSS transitions would work nicely here. However, you probably want to apply the transition to the nav's background color rather than the opacity.

```
#nav {
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
#nav.navbar-fixed {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/n8x0an7c/) a fiddle to demonstrate. After a 1 second timeout, the class "fixed" is applied to the nav.